# Rmd rendering ok. html is generated but "not found" is shown in browser

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown, rstudio-server

Got the demo Rmarkdown file for knitting a HTML report. When knitting via Rstudio Server everything goes fine and HTML is opened in a pop-up window.

Opened Rmd url in browser and report is working ok. Opened the very same report in HTML versión "Not Found" message is shown. Double checked, the HTML file is present. Permissions and owner is the same as Rmd file.

````
 ---
title: "testrender"
author: ""
date: "23/8/2017"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.
````

[UPDATED]

```
  cd reports && ls
    drwxrwxr-x  4 mick mick 4,0K ago 24 09:51 .
    drwxr-xr-x  12 mick mick 4,0K ago 18 12:42 ..
    -rw-r--r--  1 mick mick 717K ago 23 14:21 testremder.html
    -rw-r--r--  1 mick mick  832 ago 23 14:21 testremder.Rmd
```

Comment: We need to see more information about *how* you open the files and possibly the result from `ls` to be able to guess what goes wrong.

Comment: I'll try to be precise. Files are opened using Chrome browser. url is http://myserver:3838/reports/testremder.html  for HTML, same but ended in Rmd for Rmarkdown file.   Added **ls** results in question